# When to use the term "evidence against" when testing a directional hypotheses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference

In the sciences very often we are testing for the presence of a predicted relationship, for example, that two variables are positively correlated ($\beta > 0$). Under traditional frequentist testing, one might set the null hypothesis to be $H_0: \beta = 0$, with a compound alternative hypothesis of $H_{1,a}: \beta > 0$ and $H_{1,b}: \beta < 0$.

If one finds strong support for $H_{1,b}$ (that the slope is negative) is it correct to say that this is "evidence against $H_{1,a}$"? Typically we only state that we find evidence against the null hypothesis, but in the case of a directional test it seems intuitive that if you find strong evidence *for* a negative slope, then this should also count as strong evidence *against* a positive slope, not simply against the null of  $H_0: \beta = 0$.

So is it correct to say use the term "evidence against" one of the other compound alternative hypotheses? Otherwise it seems to imply that no one can ever find evidence against a presupposed hypothesis, despite evidence to its contrary. Or is it that my null and alternative hypotheses are not formed correctly?

Comment: This issue is an artefact of using a point null in a one-sided situation. You have found evidence strongly consistent with nonpositive slope.

Comment: And no support for the hypothesis of positive slope.

Comment: But what is the correct null then? If we choose $H_0: \beta > 0$ (which is what we hypothesize to be true) then this somewhat contradicts the idea of the null being "no relationship". However, if we select $H_0: \beta < 0$ then we can never "reject" $\beta > 0$ since you typically can only reject the null. And so it seems paradoxical -- how do you frame the question so that you can reject the hypothesis of a positive slope?